# Using UPDATE cursor in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, cursor, sql-update, sqlplus

As far as I can see, I can make an UPDATE in PL/SQL without using a CURSOR. 
For example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE update_my_table (id NUMBER)
AS
   ...
BEGIN
   ...
   UPDATE my_table SET column=NULL WHERE my_id = id;
   ...
END
```

I guess the cursor is only needed then if you want to perform a fetch of the updated row, is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle uses cursors under the hood for the update and for selects, which is going a bit beyond what you're asking. But no, you don't have to select the rows to be updated in a visible explicit or implicit cursor.

You don't even have to use a cursor to select the row though. you can do a [`select ... into`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/selectinto_statement.htm):

```
CREATE ... AS
    my_row my_table%rowtype;
BEGIN
    select * into my_row from my_table where my_id = id;
    -- do something with the row data
    dbms_output.put_line(my_row.my_col);
END;
```

Or you can select individual columns into separate variables instead of into a `rowtype` variable. But you have to get exactly one row (or one row's worth of columns) from the query; if there are no matches you'll get a `no data found` error, if more than one then `too many rows`. You can also select multiple rows into a PL/SQL table and manipulate the data there, still without a visible cursor.

However, if you want to select *and* update the row, you probably do want a cursor [with a `select ... for update` clause, and then `update ... where current of ...`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/static.htm#CIHHIIID) to prevent someone else modifying the data between the `select` and the `update`.

A simple update as you've got it now will be the most efficient way, whether you're updating one row or millions.

Comment: Thank you. So, if I understood it right: using an update cursor would block the selected rows until the update operation is finished.

Comment: @cortezthekiller - if you `select for update` the rows are locked until you either commit or rollback the transaction; whether you actually update them or not.